# Socratic badge: Ask a well-received question <on 100 separate days>

Tags: prepositions

The [Socratic badge page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/badges/111/socratic) states the following:

> Ask a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintain a
>   positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I wonder why the writer used the preposition *on* and not *in*. The days do not make an interval because they are separate but they are still a group and not a single day.

Comment: It's idiomatic in English to use _on_ when we refer to a specific day or calendar date: _on Friday, on September 20th,_ etc. We do typically use _in_ when we refer to a period: _in the week of September 19th,_ e.g. Here, though, each day is referenced individually because of the modifier _separate._ Parse the clause as if it reads: _Ask a well-received question on each of 100 days._

Answer (score 5):

It's *on* because these are separate days, and you ask a question  **on** a particular day.  For example, *on* a Monday, or *on* a Tuesday.  [Roughly, the rule is "on" for specific days (*on Monday*); "in" for a span of days (*in January*, or *in the last six days*).](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adverbials/adverbials-time/time-and-dates)

"In 100 days" would imply "over the span of 100 days" - i.e., you simply have to make 100 posts before 100 days are over (but you could make them all on one day if you wanted).

"In 100 separate days" isn't idiomatic, and doesn't really make sense - if they're separate, you wouldn't refer to them like a span; if they're a span, you wouldn't say "separate".